# how to put in an array some items from database?

Tags: android, database, arrays

In my app I want to put in an array some items from database. I can see them, as a list using this function :

```
private void fillData() 
{
    c = db.fetchListId(listid);
    startManagingCursor(c);

    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.listproduct, c,
                                      new String[] { DbAdapter.KEY_ITEM,
                                                     DbAdapter.KEY_QUANTITY,
                                                     DbAdapter.KEY_UNITS }, 
                                      new int[] { R.id.prod1,
                                                  R.id.prod2, 
                                                  R.id.prod3 }
                                     );

    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

But I don't know how can I put them in an array.

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: What do you want to to with the array? Of what types are the database columns?

Comment: What kind of array do you want them in? Do you want to convert the rows into objects, and have a MyObject[] array? Or do you want a multidimensional array of strings? or something else?

Comment: I want to put this array in an EditText. This will be the message I want to send and I want to look like this : "onions 1kg,pears 2 kg,..". It's about a shopping list that I want to send. The database columns are String.

Comment: I have no idea how the array should be.

Comment: here is a very nice example for what you want to do. look at the bottom of the page.  http://dharmendrajava.blogspot.com/2011/05/android-database-tutorial.html

Comment: @tarrash : exactly right ...nice tutorial for beginner ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're definitely going to begin by iterating through the cursor:

```
while(c.moveToNext()){
  myString = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("MyColumnName")); // or somesuch
  array[x][y][z] = myString; // also somesuch
}
```

Without knowing more about how you want to store the data, it's impossible to guess what you need beyond `c.moveToNext()`.

UPDATE:

OK, so you just want to accumulate them into a String. Try something like:

```
String theList="";
while(c.moveToNext()){
  theList += c.getString(0) + " " + c.getString(1) + c.getString(2) + "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you would like to do something like this:

```
private String[] getItems(<the selection params>) {
    Cursor c = db.retrieveItems(<the selection params>);
    String[] items = new String[c.getCount()];
    for (int i = 0; c.moveToNext() != null; i++) {
        String item = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DbAdapter.KEY_ITEM));
        String quantity = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DbAdapter.KEY_QUANTITY));
        String units = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DbAdapter.KEY_UNITS));
        items[i] = item + " " + quantity + units;
    }
    c.close();
    return items;
}
```

I have assumed that your DB class has a method called *retrieveItems*, that takes some selection params, in order to perform the appropriate query.
I have not tested the code, there may be some typo or minor error, but I hope it can direct you to the desired solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried something like the previuos answer and it works,but I think that this method works too.